# Rail3 Blog Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs

I have an existing Rails3 web application and would like to add a blog to it.  Just something basic, but with slugs (/blog/2011/07/permalink-to-entry).

Thoughts?

Comment: Check out Rail's own [blog tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create and mount Refinery cms as an engine in your existing app.

https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms

Comment: That's massive overkill for what I need.  Refinery is a full CMS, not a simple blog engine, and it carries along its own security.

Answer (score 0):

Refinery also has a blog engine: https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog

Comment: I don't need a full-on CMS, just a simple blog.

Comment: Typo is too heavy.  I really need something that is lightweight, does not integrate everything under the sun, and can work with whatever security gem (devise, etc.) that I choose with minimal fiddling.